# Attaching custom jQuery function on document ready and on element change

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

I have a function which hides or shows elements with a given class name:

```
$.fn.questionDetails = function(base_element, details_yes_no) {
  var details_element = '.' + base_element + '_details';
  var radio_element = '#' + base_element + '_' + details_yes_no;

  if ($(radio_element).attr('checked')) {
    $(details_element).show();
  } else {
    $(details_element).hide();
  }
}
```

I want to attach/bind this function so that it is called with the two parameters when the page is loaded and when a given radio button group is changed. At the moment I'm using the following code to accomplish this:

```
$(function() {
  // $.fn.questionDetails defined here, in same scope

  $.fn.questionDetails('question1', 'yes');
  $('input:radio[name=question1]').change().questionDetails('question1', 'yes');
}
```

The first function call works fine - when the page is loaded the question1_details panel will either be shown or hidden. However, the function does not seem to be called correctly when I change which radio button is selected, nor does it work when I modify the change() line to be this:

```
$('input:radio[name=question1]').change($.fn.questionDetails('question1', 'yes'));
```

I want to be able to say "call this function, with these parameters, when the page loads *and* when a given radio button group is changed", with the least amount of repetition. What is the best way to go about this? I'm relatively new to jQuery, so it's possible I'm doing things the 'wrong' way from the start.

Edit: Should have mentioned this originally - I'm using jQuery 1.7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign a call to a function that takes parameters (other than the event) to an event handler, you'll need to wrap that call in an anonymous function, like so:

```
$('input:radio[name=question1]').change(function() {
    $.fn.questionDetails('question1', 'yes')
});
```

Why? Because the `change()` function expects a function reference to be passed to it. When you do `change($.fn.questionDetails('question1', 'yes'))` you're passing the result of calling `$.fn.questionDetails('question1', 'yes')` to the function, rather than a function reference.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. It feels a bit wasteful to define an anonymous function to call another function rather than just referring to $.fn.questionDetails with parameters, but I don't think it will matter much in this particular project.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
$('input:radio[name=question1]').change(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $.fn.questionDetails('question1', 'yes');
});
```

In case you need to decide dynamically which params you pass to the callback, I would [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) a custom event:

```
$('input:radio[name=question1]').change(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var param1 = // A param you'd like to pass to the callback
    var param2 = // Another param
    $(this).trigger('mycustomevent', [param1, param2]);
});
```

After that, you could bind your custom event, which would be fired on your input change, accessing the params like this:

```
$('input:radio[name=question1]').on('mycustomevent', function(ev, param1, param2){
    $.fn.questionDetails(param1, param2);
});
```

EDIT:

As you can see in the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), the trigger function lets you including an array of parameters, which will be passed along to the callback function.

I'm guessing you are using jQuery 1.7 or later. If this is not the case, you must use the `bind` or `live` functions instead of `on` to attach the event.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually went with something like your first suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,instead of the `change()` function try using the `on()` function,if you are using jquery 1.7.*.
if you are using earlier versions use `bind()` or `live()`.

If you do want to use change() then do not pass the function as a parameter to change.Instead,use an anonymous function and then call your function inside that anonymous function.

Comment: What is the advantage of using .on('change', function()) over .change(function())?

Comment: @pwaring
well. using on gives you the option to off it.and for more in depth differences i am afraid i can't help you.i too am very new to jquery.you can ask the experienced guys here.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.fn.questionDetails = function(base_element, details_yes_no) {
  var details_element = '.' + base_element + '_details';
  var radio_element = '#' + base_element + '_' + details_yes_no;

    $(radio_element).change(function(){
        $(details_element).toggle();
    });
}
```